# The Function add_time(time1,time2)

Tags: python

```
def add_time(time1, time2):
    """
    Returns: The sum of time1 and time2 as a new Time object
    
    Example: Sum of 1hr 59min and 1hr 2min is 3hr 1min 
    DO NOT ALTER time1 or time2, even though they are mutable
    
    Parameter time1: the starting time
    Precondition: time1 is a Time object
    
    Parameter time2: the time to add
    Precondition: time2 is a Time object
    """
```

I have wrote the function like this,

```
minutes= time1.minutes+time2.minutes
hours= time1.hours+time2.hours

minutes=minutes %60
hours= hours+minutes//60

return Time(hours,minutes)
```

However, this function did not end up well as expected. I am trying to execute so add_time(1:30,3:40) can produce 5:10.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try:

```
def add_time(time1, time2):
    t1=time1.split(":")
    t3=time2.split(":")
    t5=":".join([str(int(x)+int(y)) for x,y in zip(t1,t3)])
    t6=t5.split(":")
    if t6[1]>'60':
        t6[1]=str(int(t6[1])-60)
        t6[0]=str(int(t6[0])+1)
    return ':'.join(t6)
print(add_time('2:30','3:50'))
```